# Logo Creation Standards/Guidlines - Gaussian Blur

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo

Is it common for logos to be created using Gaussian Blur?

Do print shops handle this appropriately?

The intention is to use it to smooth the edges of the chosen font to enhance the appeal of the design. I want to keep the design as minimalistic as possible. Gaussian Blur will deviate slightly from that rule, but I think it's worth it; given the questions above don't introduce any unforeseen complexities.

*note: this question is tagged with Photoshop, as that is the program I'm using to generate the logo.*

Answer (score 3):

Logos are usually done as a vector, because that's the best way to design them.

Raster (pixel) logos get blurry and pixelated when enlarged, which limits their practical use.

Also, the edges of the font don't need to be smoothed; because it's vector, it's  crisp and sharp no matter how large it's scaled.

FYI, you can use Photoshop to create a vector graphic.